# Binding to action in ideavim insert mode

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, vim-plugin, ideavim

I would like to be able to map actions to key bindings when in insert mode. However using the code here just inserts the text `:action EditorCompleteStatement` into the buffer.

```
inoremap <a-j> :action EditorCompleteStatement<CR>
```

Why is this not working and how can I change it to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is working exactly how it should. `inoremap` says "whenever you type *left hand side*, pretend the user typed *right hand side*". So after that mapping, `<a-j>` is literally equivalent to typing ":action EditorCompleteStatement" in insert mode.

So really all you need to do is escape insert mode first:

```
inoremap <a-j> <esc>:action EditorCompleteStatement<cr>gi
```

Or, you could use `<C-o>`, which is a bit easier in this context:

```
inoremap <a-j> <C-o>:action EditorCompleteStatement<cr>
```

Comment: For anyone interested, vim help for `i_CTRL-O` says: `execute one command, return to Insert mode`